# One PHP file not executing, others working fine (using php function "mkdir")

Tags: php, mkdir

FINAL EDIT: FIXED but not solved. Not sure what was going on, but I created a new php file from scratch and that one worked. Very strange.

Edit: I have permissions set to `777` on all related folders

Edit 2: Added quotes to strings

Edit 3: Removed `/` before `letter`

Edit 4:

```
<?php mkdir("letter/testfolder",0777); ?>
```

worked perfectly and created the folder `testfolder` within `letter`.

---

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have many php files that work on their own, but when I try to execute this particular one, the only one that uses mkdir, it does not work and it loads the index.php files instead. I assume it is due to bad coding?

The code is

```
<?php
$letters = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

foreach($letters as $letter) {
    mkdir("letter/$letter",0755);
    echo $letter;
    echo " created";
}
?>
```

The idea is to create 26 folders, one for each letter of the alphabet, inside the folder `letter`.

I feel like the answer is very obvious, but it is often my own obvious errors that I find the hardest to see.

Comment: Quote your strings! Using `a` to mean `'a'` is both a very bad idea and abuse of the language.

Comment: Ah, yes! Thanks. I changed it but no difference with the .php file working.

Comment: `mkdir("/letter/$letter",0755);` do you have folder `letter` at the root of the disk?? if you want to use a subdir to cwd, remove first / and check that folder `letter` exists.

Comment: Do you have safemode enabled?

Comment: The php file is at the root of the disk and so is the folder `letter`

Comment: @mugur I'm not sure if I have safemode enabled, but a simple `<?php
mkdir("letter/testfolder",0777);
?>` works

Comment: @Chris         You are not replacing the meaning of the `drive root` with the `website root`, aren't you?

Comment: @Cheery Yes, sorry, I meant website root

Comment: Chris   /letter/ counts from the root of the physical disk! not from the root of your site.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've changed it to `letter/$letter` but still no change.

Comment: At first you have to deal with index.php called instead of your script. Are trying to do that at the site with some kind of CMS?

Comment: No CMS, but I just fixed the problem by creating a new php file and executing that one. I have no idea why the other was not working but at least it has been sorted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir("/letter/$letter",0755);
```

Tries to create folder in the /letter/ folder located at the root of the file system. Do you have it there? If you are trying to work with subfolders of the current working directory then use

```
mkdir("letter/$letter",0755);
```

and be sure that folder `letter` already exists.

ps: `The php file is at the root of the disk and so is the folder letter` - very weird configuration. Are sure you talking about the root of the disk and not about the root of the website? Enable output of all errors in php.

If you want to create folder at the root of the site use

```
 mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/letter/$letter",0755);
```

But this is true only if you are able to run the script. You phrase about `it loads the index.php` means that you have something else in the httpd.conf (lets say that your server is Apache) of your server or in .htaccess redirecting all request to the index.php file. If you are using any CMS on the website it could be possible.

Comment: Actually if you try to make it on the root you will need special permissions since your script runs under the same user as apache does so you cannot write in there.

Comment: I meant root of the website, sorry. I tried without the / (the folder "letter" does exist) and still no change.

Comment: @Chris because `letter/` will deal with subdirectories of your current working directory. Check where you are with  `echo getcwd();`

Comment: I just fixed the problem by creating a new php file and executing that one. I have no idea why the other was not working but at least it has been sorted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a `.` before the path.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); //<<Always a good idea
foreach(range('a','z') as $letter){

mkdir("./letter/$letter",0755);
echo $letter.' created';
}
?>
```

Comment: I just fixed the problem by creating a new php file and executing that one. I have no idea why the other was not working but at least it has been sorted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you should do:

1. Enable error reporting
2. Test the result of your `mkdir` calls.

Once you do these two things, I'm guessing you'll see exactly why things aren't working for you:

```
// Useful in debug / development environments (disable in production)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

foreach ($letters as $letter)
{
    if(mkdir("/letter/$letter",0755))
        echo "$letter created\n";
    else
        echo "Failed to create $letter!\n";
}
```

Comment: No change. It just loads index.php as if the php file I just created does not even exist.

Comment: OK, so this sounds like a .htaccess kind of problem. Is your web server IIS or Apache (or something else)?

Comment: Apache I think - but I just fixed the problem by creating a new php file and executing that one. I have no idea why the other was not working but at least it has been sorted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i was stuck with this for a long time, perhaps this was your issue. if you are on SELinux there is an extra layer of permissions called "Security Context" which you can see with `ls -alZ`. use something like `chcon system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 public_HTML`

it would make sense that the same file in different directories would work or fail, depending on this extra layer. hth